# Why symlink not working in php artisan serve in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet, valet

I just tried the symbolic link in laravel, and it is working fine when I'm using valet.

But when I use `php artisan serve` command, it returns `404 error`. I've read a lot regarding this topic but none of them works. Maybe you have an idea?

**404 when using: php artisan serve**

- `asset('storage/images/me.jpeg')`
- `url('/') . '/' . 'storage/images/me.jpg'`
- `'/storage/images/me.jpg'`

Comment: if you are working in local, and you upload it on the server, you need to recreate the link

Comment: @Berto99 How can I recreate the link?

Comment: delete it and relauch the command

Comment: Delete the `app` folder inside `storage`?

Comment: By the way, I just cloned it from old project and didn't upload yet on the server.

Comment: no, inside the public folder you should see the link

Comment: which one? https://i.imgur.com/tJppL7B.png

Comment: google is your friend https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-i-undo-php-artisan-storagelink

Comment: Didn't know that is so simple. @Berto99 You can add your answer to I can give you the check, also to make it reference for other developers facing this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you change the server (so for example form local to production, or you download a repo from somewhere), you need to recreate the symbolic link that links `storage` to `public` (check [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-i-undo-php-artisan-storagelink) for more)